Does wasysym supports Unicode characters?
Just want to know that whether the wasysym.sty supports Unicode characters? I'm using XeLaTeX in Win10 system, please advise.
Also, if possible, kindly advise the advantage and disadvantage using wasysym symbols as in Unicode characters, please

The way font is a legacy 8 bit symbol font, but you could map most of its characters to unicode just as math characters are, but what is your question, are you asking about using unicode in the input document or that unicode is used in the resulting output?
